# How to show a (hidden) <td> on button click using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-table

I want to show a `<td>` on button press. The TD should also be in a hidden state and page load.
The `<td>` I want to show also contains a drop down list. I want this `<select>` to be displayed on first button click.

My Angular table created  using ng-repeat is :

```
<div class="widget-content" ng-controller="getAllBenchersController">

  <table ng-table="talentPoolList" show-filter="true" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr ng-repeat="employee in data | filter: testFilter">
    <td data-title="'#'">{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Select Account'">
            <select>
                <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
                <option id="selectedLocked">Blocked</option>
                <option id="selectedBilled">Billed<//option>
                <option id="selectedShadow">Shadow</option>
                <option id="selectedOnNotice">OnNotice</option>
                <option id="selectedPOC">POC</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a><button class="btn  btn-success"  ng-model="checked">Reserve</button></a>
        </td>

    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Then I want the button to post a data on its second click. I can do that, but the code for displaying the `<td>` should not affect the working of second button click function.
I am new to Angular and have no clue how to achieve this.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use scope variables, [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) and [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf):

Start by setting your `visible` variable to true:

```
app.controller('controller', function($scope) {
     $scope.visible = false;
});
```

and change your td to use ng-if:

```
<td data-title="'Select Account'" ng-if="visible">
```

then, simply change visible value on ng-click:

```
<a><button ng-click="visible = true">Reserve</button></a>
```

### Edit 1

OP requested an ng-click with a custom function, to perform some more complex code.

Add this listener to the controller:

```
$scope.click = function(){
   if($scope.clicked)
     mySecondFunction(); //this is called the second time users clicks. You can do whatever you want here.

   $scope.clicked = true;
}
```

and change your button to use this new shiny function:

```
<a><button ng-click="click()">Reserve</button></a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake while making the question. It was the opposite way.

Comment: On second click of the button, I want it to run another function. The above code would contradict with that?

Comment: the current code isn't able to do that. To perform more complex functions, call a custom function on ng-click, like so: ng-click="myFunction" and declare it in the controller

Comment: and can I use your code to achieve show() of the hidden td within the function?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand you right, but i'll edit my post to show you an example.

Comment: For example, on 1st button click, I want the hidden <td> to be displayed. 
The user will then see a dropdown list populated(drop down list is inside the td) on first click. Then he will select an option from the drop down list and then click on the same button again. This time on button click, i want to run a function having a different use.

Answer (score 1):

Upon clicking on the button you can set a boolean value. Use this boolean value to show or hide td using ng-show

```
<td ng-show="showData" data-title="'#'">{{$index + 1}}</td>
```

and in click:

```
<a><button class="btn  btn-success" ng-click="showData= !showData">Reserve</button></a>
```

You can also use ng-if

Comment: On second click of the button, I want it to run another function. The above code would contradict with that?

Comment: You can call a controller function upon ng-click. In the controller function, you can decide whether you need to hide or call another function. Hope i answered your question